# Child div is greater than parent div on hover

Tags: css

I am creating a narrow sidebar menu and when I hover a menu item, it should expand tho show he whole text. The hover part is working, but it does not show the entire div content beyond the parent div boundaries.

```
.menu-bar {
  width: 80px;
}
.menu-bar-item {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-bar-item:hover {
  width: 320px;
  z-index: 50;
}

<div class="menu-bar menu-bar-main menu-bar-wide">
  <ul class="menu-bar-list">
    <li class="menu-bar-item">
      Very very very very very long name
    </li>
    <li class="menu-bar-item">
      Very very very very very long name
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I created a Fiddle to show the problem live: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljxa0osu/1/

Comment: You need to change the width of the `.menu-bar` not the list items to start. - https://jsfiddle.net/7mxg3h8a/

Comment: ^ and z-index apply to positionned element and you are missing a `.` befor the class name

Comment: @Paulie_D this would be one approach, but I don't want to expand the whole menu, but only the hovered item to create a floating box above the other content.

Comment: @TemaniAfif the missing `.` was just a mistake during copy/paste... :-)

Comment: Then remove the `overflow:hidden` from the `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *.menu-bar-list* has property *overflow:hidden*. Remove it.

Comment: This solved partially the issue. I also had to add a `z-index:50;` to the .menu-bar. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

try removing `overflow: hidden;` from `.menu-bar-list`

Answer (score 0):

remove the   .menu-bar property width